# What is the 'application standard' referred to in EN 1993-1-7

Tags: structural-analysis, structures, standards

I'm using the Eurocodes for some structural analysis and am looking for the limiting value of deflection of a plate.
EN 1993-1-7, Section 8.2 states:
*For limiting values of out of plane deflection w see application standard.*

I'm not sure to which application standard this is referring.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is ever looking for a limiting case for deflection of plates, in relation to the Eurocodes, you can find this in:

EN 1993-4-1 Section 9.8.2 (2)

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: If this is the correct answer, why do you still have @alephzero's marked as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

I think it means the relevant section of EN 1993 for the specific *use* (application) of the plated structure. A partial table of contents of EN 1993 includes

- Part 2: Steel Bridges
- Part 3-1: Towers, masts and chimneys
- Part 3-2: Towers, masts and chimneys - Chimneys
- Part 4-1: Silos
- Part 4-2: Tanks
- Part 4-3: Pipelines
- Part 5: Piling
- Part 6: Crane supporting structures